# Shortcode returning specific content of a post

Tags: plugins, posts, database, shortcode, content

I'm currently building a plugin to display specific part of post after accepting verification code. Can a shortcode return a part of a post? I mean:

Bla bla bla
[shortcode postID="100"]
Special bla bla
[/shortcode]
Bla bla

How to code a function to retrieve specific content of a post only when the plugin calls this shortcode?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use something like:

```
Bla bla bla [shortcode postID="100" content="Special bla bla"] Bla bla
```

and then retrieve your content in your shortcode function.

```
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
   'content' => '',
), $attr ) );

echo 'special content is: '.$content;
```

Comment: I meant something different. Shortcode will be used to receive large texts, only 2-3 paragraphs will be available outside shortcode. All the styling etc. would be gathered from database within shortcode.